# Webpack bundle imports whole package defined as external

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I have package with icons (package A) that when used in other app (webpack or vite - does not matter) always includes icons that where imported which is 100% valid.
Problem appears when the same icons package is used in package B (webpack) with `externals` provided to ignore bundling of all dependencies (with use of https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals).
Then application that is using package B imports every single icon from package A.

I tried few configuration options like `library.type = 'module'`, `externalsPresets.web = true` and many others but nothing seems to work. From what I understand using externals with `externalsPresets.node = true` forces bundle to use `require` and that causes all the trouble but is there any way to solve it?
Inside package B bundle there is part that I think is forcing all icons to be included

```
de=require("packageA");
...{icon: de.Info}...
```

and I think that because of that part final application is loading whole package A

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only thing that worked for me was moving to rollup.js